# First time looping through a DataGridView much slower than subsequent loops

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've written a process to export the contents of a DataGridView to Excel. While doing speed testing, I noticed something: the first time I loop through the DataGridView's rows (after populating its DataSource) is much slower than the second time.

I tried various ways of doing the loop, but all produced the same results. To eliminate anything in my export process that might be causing this, I worked up this simple loop:

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvView.Rows
        Dim s As String = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
    Next
```

I tested it on a dgv with roughly 420K rows. It takes 22 seconds to run the first time, and less than a tenth of a second to run each subsequent time after that. If I repopulate the DataGridView (by setting it's DataSource to be a DataTable) and run the code again, it will go back to taking ~20 seconds the first time and then run almost instantly every time after that.

I want to know what's causing this behavior. I thought maybe it had something to do with reading the DataTable for the first time, but if I do a loop through the datatable itself, no such behavior occurs (it's just as fast the first time). If I can figure out what causes it, maybe I can work around it. It's slowing down my larger exports by almost twice as much.

Comment: My gut feeling would be is some internal memory management and caching.  First run through, that internal memory management stuff doesn't exist, and that's why subsequent runs are soo much quicker

Comment: Could you write it to use the datatable instead of the DGV? You noted that it is consistently fast using the datatable, but didn't mention why that is not an aoption.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, unfortunately. The dgv contains several aspects which the datatable does not. The contents of the dt is most of what's in the dgv, but there are other things (like hidden columns, hidden rows, subtotals, etc) which only exist in the dgv, and which need to be factored in when exporting the data.